# The differentiability of $f$ implies that $f'$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$.
Then it is
 continuous. Note the following example : $$ f(x) =
\left\{
                                                    \begin{array}{ll}
                                                      x^2/2, & \hbox{$x\geq 0 $;} \\
                                                      -x^2/2, & \hbox{$x\leq 0$;} \\
                                                    \end{array}
                                                  \right. $$ Then
$f$ is differentiable at $0$ : $$ |\frac{f(x)-f(0) }{x-0} -0|\leq
|x|/2< \delta =\varepsilon $$

Here I have a **question** : The following is possible ? : If $f$ is
differentiable on $(a,b),\ a<b$, then $f'$ is not continuous.

**Two Variable Case** : In two variable, there exists an
example : Consider
$$ f(x,y) =\left\{
                      \begin{array}{ll}
                        \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}, & \hbox{$(x,y)\neq (0,0)$;} \\
                        0, & \hbox{$(x,y)=(0,0)$.}
                      \end{array}
                    \right. $$

$f$ is a continuous at $(0,0)$. And there exist continuous partial
derivatives $f_x,\ f_y$ around $(0,0)$. Hence differential $Df$
exists and it is continuous (i.e., entries are continuous). Now
consider $$g:=f_x = \frac{x^4y +4x^2y^3-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\ (x,y)\neq
(0,0),\ g(0,0)=0 $$

Here (1) $$ g_x(0,0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f_x(x,0)-0}{x-0}
=0$$ so that $g_x$ exists.

(2) $$g_y(0,0)=-1$$ and $$(x,y)\neq (0,0),\ g_y=\frac{h_y
(x^2+y^2)-4yh }{(x^2+y^2)^3} = \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}(1+
\frac{8x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} ) ,\ h:=x^4y +4x^2y^3-y^5
$$

Clearly $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} g_y \neq 0 $. Hence $g_y$ is
not continuous. In the long run, $Dg$ exists but it is not
continuous. In one variable, this happen ? Thank you.

Comment: Integrate a function which has a single jump discontinuity. The result will be a differentiable function with discontinuous derivative.

Comment: That is not true. If you integrate the sgn function, you end up with |x|, which is not differentiable at x=0.

Here is an example: http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_differentiable_function_need_not_be_continuous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f'$ has to have the intermediate value property but it does not have to be continuous. The standard example is 
$$
f(x) = x^2 \sin (1/x).
$$
with $f(0) =0.$

Comment: f(x) is not defined at x=0 ;)

Comment: @avid19 But $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists.

Comment: It does exist, but your f(x) is not differentiable at x=0, as it is not even continuous there!

Comment: ok i have clarified that $f(0) =0.$ it certainly is continuous at zero.

Comment: you need $x^2$ not $x$ i have changed this.